# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value

Tags: java, jackson, wordpress-json-api

I am trying to convert my json string to java object and I am getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude$Value
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:45)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:535)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:452)
    at com.allianz.cmis.util.ApacheHttpClientGet.main(ApacheHttpClientGet.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is my json string and my code snippet

json string
`{'ctpnsw': [{'abc' , 'def' }]}`

Model

```
    public class Fields {
        
         private List<String> ctpnsw;
    
        public List<String> getCtpnsw() {
            return ctpnsw;
        }
    
        public void setCtpnsw(List<String> ctpnsw) {
            this.ctpnsw = ctpnsw;
        }
        
    }
```

Java code

```
`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                List<Fields> list = mapper.readValue(output, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class,Fields.class));
                System.out.println(list);`
```

Answer (score 104):

How about adding this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where should pom.xml be placed?

Comment: @BakedInhalf It should be in your root source directory

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023961/cannot-run-testng-test-due-to-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jack

Comment: I used 2.12.0 and it worked :) Thanks a lot @MonoThreaded

Answer (score 72):

Jackson marshalling/unmarshalling requires following jar files of same version.

1. jackson-core
2. jackson-databind
3. jackson-annotations

   Make sure that you have added all these with same version in your classpath. In your case **jackson-annotations** is missing in classpath.

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023961/cannot-run-testng-test-due-to-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jack

Comment: Besides the same version the dependencies should be defined as one could get transient dependencies with different versions.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same error message. In my case, Jackson consisted of multiple JAR files. Sadly, they had different versions of jackson-core and jackson-annotations which resulted in the above exception.

Maybe you don't have the jackson-annotation JAR in your classpath, at least not in the correct version. You can analyze the used library versions with the command [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).

Comment: JAX-RS and jsonschema2pojo, for example have different jackson versions as dependencies (in maven).  Forcing a specific version (in dependency management) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 21):

I had different version of annotations jar. Changed all 3 jars to use **SAME version** of databind,annotations and core jackson jars

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 16):

Even though this answer was too late, I'm adding it because I also went through a horrible time finding answer for the same matter. Only different was, I was struggling with AWS Comprehend Medical API.

At the moment I'm writing this answer, if anyone come across the same issue with any AWS SDKs please **downgrade jackson-annotaions or any jackson dependencies to 2.8.* versions.** 
The latest 2.9.* versions does not working properly with AWS SDK for some reason. Anyone have any idea about the reason behind that feel free to comment below.

Just in case if anyone is lazy to google maven repos, I have linked down necessary repos.Check them out!

- [Jackson-Core Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core)
- [Jackson-Core-Databind - 2.8.11.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.11.3)
- [Jackson-Core - 2.8.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.6)
- [Jackson Annotations - 2.8.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.8.11)

Comment: Now, instead of downgrading, you can use the new 2.10.0 version, which fixed it for me.

Comment: You sir are my hero today.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was having a similar issue in my project after upgrading Spring Boot version from 2.1 to 2.4, using v2.10.0 as suggested here resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the similar issues and by referring to the above solutions i was able to resolve the issue.

**All the dependencies must have same version**.

Following are the dependencies added in the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>


 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
 </dependency>


 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Get all 3 jackson jars and add them to your build path:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Comment: How to add to build path ? in intellij

Answer (score 3):

Use jackson-bom which will have all the three jackson versions.i.e.jackson-annotations, jackson-core and jackson-databind. This will resolve the dependencies related to those versions

Answer (score 0):

this is a version problem 
change version > 2.4 to 1.9 solve it

```
<dependency>  
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>  
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>  
<version>2.4.1</version>
```

to

```
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
<version>1.9.4</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start adding required `jackson` related jars which helps in converting `JSON` to `POJO` and `POJO` to `JSON` responses. (`jackson-core`, `jackson-annotations`, `jackson-databind`). Lets pretend you have already added these Jar still you're facing this issue here are some of the trouble shooting steps

***TROUBLE SHOOTING STEPS:***

1. First check if they are any conflicts with any other jackson related jars which comes with different spring/java related jars with maven command `mvn dependecy:tree` if you find any conflicting jackson jars try excluding them like below

```
   <exclusion>      
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>  
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>    
   </exclusion>   
   </<exclusions>
```

2. If you didn't find any conflicts then go to you're local maven .m2 directory (storage for all local maven dependencies) verify the expecting class is part of the jar.

`cd (.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.2.2)`

`jar -xvf` this command will explode the jar and generates all the corresponding classes

3. If it didn't worked still try deleting/re importing jackson related folder from local repository (.m2). you can re import by executing maven command (`mvn clean install`)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry late to party but Using below dependency solved my problem.

Attached link:
https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir/issues/156

```java
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks @dorian349 for adding the dependency tag.

Answer (score 0):

Excluse jackson-core and jackson-annotations from your jackson-databind dependency.
They try to add them seperately.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please remember that all dependencies have to be the same version.

Answer (score -3):

Use Jackson-annotations.jar will solve the problem, as it worked for me.

Comment: Can you give more details about your answer