# Receiving data as JSON object

Tags: java, json

I in my controller class a have the following method:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/message")
public String postMessage(Json json,
    @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
   System.out.println("message");
   return "ok";
}
```

The problem is when I send `POST` by executing `curl` by:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X 
POST -d '{"key":"value"}' http://localhost:8080/message
```

I get `HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type` as if I didn't send JSON. When I change `Json json,` to `String body` the controller works fine.

In `web.xml` I have:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

**EDIT**

I had wrong JSON as suggested in the comments. However, even with a correct one like `{"key":"value"}` the code won't work.

Comment: Do you have JSON mapping enabled in your JAX-RS implementation?

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: Is it the correct url you are using? From the code you posted it should be `http://localhost:8080/message` rather than `http://localhost:8080/get/message`

Comment: It's different. I changed it to `http://localhost:8080/message` now for convenience.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht I think I have. Please check my updated post.

Comment: You are also sending incorrect json: `'{"key":"value", "user"}'` - is is not a valid one, add a value to  'user'.

Comment: Did you try to expect as parameter a POJO instead of javax.json.Json? Something like `public String postMessage(MyMessage msg) { }` where `MyMessage` is a class with `String key` field.

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know jersey uses jackson's ObjectMapper to deserialize stuff. I think the problem may be that object mapper dont know how to map your request to `javax.json.Json` object, a simple test:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
// (...)
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Json json = mapper.readValue("{\"key\": \"value\"}", Json.class);
```

This produces an exception:

```
UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "key" (class javax.json.Json)
```

I think you should create a POJO instead of raw json objects, for example:

```
class MyMessage {
  public String key; //for simplicity, you probably will use accessor methods
}
```

And the same test works fine:

```
MyMessage msg = mapper.readValue("{\"key\": \"value\"}", MyMessage.class);
```

and then your controller method should look like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/message")
public String postMessage(MyMessage msg) {
  System.out.println(msg.key);
  return "ok";
}
```

Comment: You were right about object mapper not knowing how to map. I had missing dependencies and I [solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406070/2657875). Now `MyMessage msg = mapper.readValue("{\"key\": \"value\"}", MyMessage.class);
` works great. However, I still get an error `Unsupported Media Type`. I'm using your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. In a class that extends `ResourceConfig` there has to be `register(JacksonFeature.class)` instruction, e.g.:

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        super(MyController.class);

        property(CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have an implementation of
[MessageBodyReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) in your classpath, that could consume JSON