# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMer

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jar, jackson, objectmapper

In my jar source code, I'm getting the above error while trying to create an object for ObjectMapper

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

This is not a maven project and all dependency jars are in lib folder.And Im using jackson 2.9.8 version How to solve this error?

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023961/cannot-run-code-due-to-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-ann

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run code due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023961/cannot-run-code-due-to-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-ann)