# How to solve error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView"

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to evaluate a json string using the jackson library ObjectMapper. I have added the **jackson-annotaion** ,j**ackson-databind** and **jackson-core** dependencies with the **same version** in the pom.xml file too.But code gives following error.I checked the simillar questions but i don,t have version mismach as in their cases.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:37)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:348)
    at com.company.EvaluateJson.evaluate(EvaluateJson.java:49)
    at com.company.DataMapper.doMapping(DataMapper.java:58)
    at com.company.DataMapper.getRequest(DataMapper.java:49)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

My code is as follows:

```
 try{
            ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();

            String jString=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestMap);
            JsonNode jsonNode=objectMapper.readTree(jString);
            System.out.println("From jsonNode:"+jsonNode.get("name"));
        }catch (JsonGenerationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (JsonMappingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.12.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.12.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
           <version>2.12.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
           <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
           <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.0</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Comment: please show your pom

Comment: @Jens Added the pom in the question.

Comment: Is the part you show us under `<dependencyManagement>`?

Comment: @Jens yeah. dependencies are under <dependencyManagement>

Comment: Pur ist outside

Answer (score 1):

can you try adding this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: similar solution added here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569092/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-fasterxml-jackson-annotation-jsonincludev

Comment: I have the mentioned dependency .But it still gives the error.